# Database generation when deploying war to Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, deployment, war

I have a war file with my webapp and I need to generate the database tables in MySQL in the moment when I have copied the war to the webapps folder from Tomcat (assuming Tomcat is running).

Is there a way to do this, can you help me with some information about this?

PS. It's a very simple webapp, using just JDBC, i don't use any ORM frameworks. Is it possible with JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the job in the `contextInitialized()` method of a custom [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) class. This will be invoked when the webapp starts up.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Just write/call JDBC code here the usual way to create database/tables if not exists.
    }

    // ...
}
```

That said, using an ORM framework like JPA/Hibernate really saves you from **a lot** of JDBC boilerplate code and headaches.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to update the schema, but don't want to introduce something as heavyweight as Hibernate, there are some good alternatives:

- [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) - Provide migration scripts with your application to update it at deployment time.
- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) - Provide XML description of your schema, and allow Liquibase to update the schema.

Flyway requires you to write the SQL to migrate between different versions of your application. It doesn't generate any DDL (SQL for modifying the schema) at all. It just runs the SQL you give it. If you're comfortable with SQL, and want to be able to use all the features your database provides, I can strongly recommend this.

The code to start the migration can be put into a ServletContextListener. Example code that could be used there is given on the [Flyway Application Integration](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api.html) page.

Liquibase works by reading an XML file describing the schema changes necessary to upgrade your database to the latest schema. These changes are applied in order. This means that your schema and changes are more likely to be portable to other databases, but it's arguably harder to take advantage of features that are specific to your database.

Liquibase provides its own ServletContextListener that you can use. See the [ServletListener](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/servlet_listener) page in the docs.

If you do want to introduce an ORM, you could look at:

- [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) - ORM with lots of features (and quite a few dependencies)
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) - previously Oracle TopLink. This seems more polished than Hibernate, but has fewer features.

Comment: For a proprietary application that I didn't plan to distribute, I would use Flyway. If I was writing an open-source application and wanted to support many databases, I might lean towards Liquibase.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a case for  : http://www.hibernate.org/